# Updating MYSQL data point based on if another data point is not null?

Tags: mysql, database

I'm not entirely sure how to properly structure this. I have `nextBillingDate` and `currentTime` data points on a table. `currentTime` should ONLY populate if nextBillingDate is not null.

```
UPDATE `Users`
SET
`current_time` = <{current_time}>
WHERE <{where_expression}>;
```

All I did here was right click on currentTime and select the UPDATE statement query since I only want to update this when another value is not NULL.

Comment: `UPDATE Users
SET  current_time = CURRENT_TIME WHERE nextBillingDate IS NOT NULL` I would also add `and current_time is null` so you don't overwrite those values already set

Comment: UPDATE `Users`
SET
`current_time` = current_time
WHERE 'next_billing_time' IS NOT NULL;

Like this?
@GeorgeGarchagudashvili

Comment: I've added the comment. so it should be like this: `UPDATE users SET users.current_time = CURRENT_TIME WHERE nextBillingDate IS NOT NULL AND users.current_time IS NULL`

Comment: I added my comment same as you lol. So like this?

UPDATE `Users`
SET
`current_time` = current_time
WHERE 'next_billing_time' IS NOT NULL AND 'current_time' IS NULL;

@GeorgeGarchagudashvili

Comment: Okay, thank you haha!

Comment: 'current_time' is is wrong because if you use single quotes it's no longer field name but string. you should use back-ticks instead if necessary,

Comment: It's just very bad practice to use a field name that is the same name as a system function. Also, "current" time is semantically inaccurate. At which point is or was "current" within your model logic? Instead you should use good practice namings like `modified_at`, `created_at`, ...

Comment: Then, the thing you want to do is a hidden implication. Structure your data properly, using foreign keys and relations, not hidden logic "if this field is blank, that field does this,...". Modelling like that tends to corrupt data at some point.